# how to customize login form in azure b2c sign in page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to edit the default sign in page. I want to remove "Email Address" and "Password" labels from the sign-in form and only display input textboxes with default placeholders for both fields shown on the azure b2c signup page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6h4C.png)

Please refer any documentation i can further refer into.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment to read these "How to Ask" topics https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.  As it is, your question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the sign-in page UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) using a custom stylesheet.

For example, to hide the field labels, use the following style:

```css
.attrEntry label {
  display: none;
}
```